# How do I set a property in a polymer-dart behavior mixin?

Tags: dart-polymer

The following example is taken from the polymer-dart [documentation on behaviors](https://github.com/dart-lang/polymer-dart/wiki/behaviors#defining-behaviors). It makes use of the method `set` in `toggleHighlight`. I don't understand how this is possible since `set` isn't defined anywhere.

```
@behavior
abstract class HighlightBehavior {
  @Property(notify: true, observer: 'highlightChanged')
  bool isHighlighted = false;

  static created(instance) {
    print('Highlighting for $instance enabled!');
  }

  @Listen('click')
  toggleHighlight(_, __) {
    set('isHighlighted', !isHighlighted);
  },

  @reflectable
  highlightChanged(bool newValue, _) {
    toggleClass('highlighted', newValue);
  }
}
```

How do I set a polymer property in a behavior that triggers all the functionality that makes data binding work?

Should a behavior possibly implement `PolymerBase` to be able to use the `set`-method? A quick test reveals that `set` works when the behavior implements `PolymerBase`. But this is not how it is documented. May I induce some unwanted side-effects by implementing `PolymerBase`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `HighlightBehavior` is abstract, so real instances are obtained with inheritance. From the documentation

```
class MyElement extends PolymerElement with HighlightBehavior {
  MyElement.created() : super.created();
}
```

The `PolymerElement` extends `PolymerBase` which supply the `set` method.

Comment: Thank you, now I understand.

Coming from Java it will take some time getting used to this feature.

Comment: Great:-) Behaviors is complicated and the documentation of behaviors  spares, so not evident. After fibbling around with some code, things became more clear to me. Actually I have so fare not needed to write own behaviors, started once, but the needed functionality was already in the polymer_elements lib.

Comment: I'm building a framework für a business application where I want to use behaviors for elements to expose a common API. See the following example where `view-companies` and `view-users` mix in the `ViewBehavior` allowing the shell element to deal with its children. `<shell> <view-users default-view></view-users> <view-companies></view-companies> </shell>` I think this use-case of grouping common functionality meets the idea of behaviors.

Comment: Wrote a Behavior to my project, it works ok. Now I see it is hard to track the set method, the dart analyzer also marks this with warning. As long as Behaviors is mixin to PolymerElements it works.

Comment: Exactly, the analyzer marks it too because it is really hard to know (for the machine and me in the beginning *gg*) that this behavior (ordinary dart mixin) will only be used in a class which has such a method.